# jQuery Post + MVC flow

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i need some help.

```
<button id="link-button">Link Account</button>

<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var handler = Plaid.create({
  clientName: 'Plaid Walkthrough Demo',
  env: 'sandbox',
  key: '[PUBLIC_KEY]', // Replace with your public_key to test with live credentials
  product: ['auth', 'transactions'],
  webhook: '[WEBHOOK_URL]', // Optional – use webhooks to get transaction and error updates
  selectAccount: false, // Optional – trigger the Select Account
  onLoad: function() {
    // Optional, called when Link loads
  },
  onSuccess: function(public_token, metadata) {
    // Send the public_token to your app server.
    // The metadata object contains info about the institution the
    // user selected and the account ID, if `selectAccount` is enabled.
    $.post('/plaid/exchangetoken', {
      public_token: public_token,
    });
  },
  onExit: function(err, metadata) {
    // The user exited the Link flow.
    if (err != null) {
      // The user encountered a Plaid API error prior to exiting.
    }
    // metadata contains information about the institution
    // that the user selected and the most recent API request IDs.
    // Storing this information can be helpful for support.
  }
});

$('#link-button').on('click', function(e) {
  handler.open();
  // Alternatively, you can have a specific institution
  // prompt for authentication. Example:
  //
  // handler.open('ins_100000');
  //
  // This will open Link with Union Bank as the institution.
});
</script>
```

Here i recieve the public_token and send it to my controller, next I exchange it in the controller for an access_token.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExchangeToken(string public_token)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://development.plaid.com/item/public_token/exchange");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("postman-token", "c4c60478-e5c2-3ef7-5b3f-74a1d6ab871c");
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\t\"client_id\" : \"xxxxx\",\n\t\"public_token\" : \"" + public_token + "\",\n\t\"secret\" : \"xxxxxx\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            var content = response.Content;

            JToken token = JObject.Parse(content);

            var access_token = token.SelectToken("access_token").ToString();
            var item_id = token.SelectToken("item_id").ToString();

            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            var client2 = new RestClient("https://development.plaid.com/transactions/get");
            var request2 = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request2.AddHeader("postman-token", "e55586a7-dc79-e4a8-6f1f-ac2d7030c582");
            request2.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request2.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request2.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\t\"client_id\" : \"xxxxxxx\",\n\t\"secret\" : \"xxxxxxxxx\",\n\t\"access_token\" : \"" + access_token + "\",\n\t\"start_date\" : \"2017-01-01\",\n\t\"end_date\" : \"2017-07-07\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            IRestResponse response2 = client2.Execute(request2);

            var content2 = response2.Content;

            JToken token2 = JObject.Parse(content2);

            var transactions = token2.SelectToken("transactions").ToString();

            return PartialView("Index", transactions);
        }
```

The problem is that the view is not rendering with the transactions

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to see the transactions variable in the ExchangeToken action method when you are debugging and if you have a view named Index.cshtml with the code below, you should see the result:

@model string

Value: @Model

Comment: Yeah thats the problem, its not showing it, I tried the way u said

Comment: What does your javascript do? I can't see anywhere that you are replacing the html with the partial view content returned from your controller. Are you able to see if the jQuery post is working fine without any errors?

Comment: Yes, jquery post is working fine, i get the public_token, as I said it also returns me the transactions. But it's not showing even the partial view, no matter what I type in it.

Comment: It will be good to see the actual code that you are using in your javascript (without the credentials).